# CMake custom build step PRE_LINK/PRE_BUILD do not work

Tags: cmake

PRE_LINK and PRE_BUILD do not seem to work in CMake on linux ( generating MakeFiles ). The documentation says that only PRE_BUILD is not supported. But , PRE_LINK does not wrok at all.

I was not sure if understood them wrong or if I am missing something.

( For now,as workaround I added a fake target and POST_BUILD step on it. Then creating dependency worked. But, it has its own issues.For my setup , it creates problems when parallel make ( -j ) is done.

Example Code :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5)
project(custom_command_test)

add_custom_target(my_actual_target
    COMMAND echo " I am the actual taget "
    COMMENT "Running actual target"
    )
add_custom_command(
    TARGET my_actual_target
    PRE_LINK
    COMMAND echo "I am prelinked to actual target"
    COMMENT " Running PRELINK action "
    )
add_custom_command(
    TARGET my_actual_target
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND echo " I am prebuilt to actual target"
    COMMENT " Running PRE_BUILD action"
    )
add_custom_command(
    TARGET my_actual_target
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND echo " I postbuild to actual target"
    COMMENT " Running POST BUILD action "
    )
```

Output :

```
> cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.4.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.4.2
-- Check for working C compiler: XXXX/gcc/4.4.2/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: XXXX/gcc/4.4.2/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: XXXX/gcc/4.4.2/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: XXXX/gcc/4.4.2/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: XXXX

 > make my_actual_target
Scanning dependencies of target my_actual_target
[100%] Running actual target
 I am the actual taget 
 Running PRE_BUILD action
 I am prebuilt to actual target
 Running POST BUILD action 
 I postbuild to actual target
[100%] Built target my_actual_target

> cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.10.2
```

Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `PRE_LINK` works only for the "real" targets like library or executable:

```
add_library(my_actual_target foo.cpp)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET my_actual_target
    PRE_LINK
    COMMAND echo "I am prelinked to actual target"
    COMMENT " Running PRE_LINK action "
    )
add_custom_command(
    TARGET my_actual_target
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND echo " I am prebuilt to actual target"
    COMMENT " Running PRE_BUILD action"
    )
add_custom_command(
    TARGET my_actual_target
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND echo " I postbuild to actual target"
    COMMENT " Running POST_BUILD action "
    )
```

Result:

```
Running PRE_BUILD action
...
Running PRE_LINK action
...
Running POST_BUILD action
```

*IMHO it's documentation issue*

Comment: But what about PRE_LINK/PRE_BUILD commands getting run *before* the actual TARGET ? In my example above , PRE_BUILD is built/run *after* the actual TARGET .

Comment: Looks like you were right !! This is considered documentation issue. Here is the bug report : http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15059